# Как проверить правильность ввода текста?

Tags: python, while

Начинаю изучать python. Есть задание создать симуляцию игры в рулетку. Решил сперва разбить ставки четные и нечетные. Пробую произвести проверку через while not на ключевые слова. Но проверка всегда дает ответ что введенное слово неверно. Как можно по другому написать код чтобы сработало?

```
typeofbet = input(str("Введите вид вашей ставки строго \"Внешняя\" либо \"Внутренняя\"" '\n'))
while not typeofbet == str("Внешняя") or typeofbet == str("Внутренняя"):
    print ("Вид ставки введен некорректно"'\n')
    typeofbet = input(str("Введите вид вашей ставки строго \"Внешняя\"либо \"Внутренняя\"" '\n'))
else:
    print ("Вид ставки принят")
```

Comment: `not (...)` ???

Comment: Во-первых, `not` относится только к `typeofbet == str("Внешняя")` а к тому, что после or уже не относится, во-вторых, `typeofbet` будет всегда или не равно "Внешняя" или не равно "Внутренняя", поэтому ``or`` нужно заменить на ``and``.  В-третьих ``"Внешняя"`` уже является строкой, поэтому еще раз переводить строку в строку не имеет смысла. Все четыре ``str()`` из кода нужно убрать, они абсолютно ничего не дают, а поэтому бесполезны, и даже вредны.

Comment: Спасибо. Изначально так и было. Это уже я экспериментировал надеясь что добавление конкретики заставит проверку работать

Comment: @Эникейщик Нее..., если завернуть в скобки `not (...)`, то как раз `or`. А если `and`, то вместо `not` можно использовать `!=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Странно, у меня все работает. Может вы не соблюли регистр букв или что-то в этом роде? Если бы я делал код, то я бы перевел ответ игрока в нижний регистр и создал бы массив с правильными ответами:

```
typeofbet = input(str("Введите вид вашей ставки строго \"Внешняя\" либо \"Внутренняя\"" '\n'))
allowed = ["внешняя", "внутренняя"] # Правильные ответы в нижнем регистре!
while not typeofbet in allowed:
    print ("Вид ставки введен некорректно"'\n')
    typeofbet = input(str("Введите вид вашей ставки строго \"Внешняя\"либо \"Внутренняя\"" '\n'))
else:
    print ("Вид ставки принят")
```

или бы просил цифру вместо целого слова:

```
typeofbet = input(str("Введите вид вашей ставки строго 1: \"Внешняя\" либо 2: \"Внутренняя\"" '\n'))
allowed = ["1", "2"] # Правильные ответы в нижнем регистре!
while not typeofbet in allowed:
    print ("Вид ставки введен некорректно"'\n')
    typeofbet = input(str("Введите вид вашей ставки строго \"Внешняя\"либо \"Внутренняя\"" '\n'))
else:
    print ("Вид ставки принят")
```

Comment: Спасибо. Без Allowed но через цифры я уже пробовал. Без понятия почему не работает. По крайней мере я понимаю иду в верном направлении.

UPD. Это уже вообще не смешно но ваш код у меня не работает.

UPD2. Оказалось что все это время мне делал мозг Anakonda Navigator через который я запускал VSCode. :)